# Why is my systemd-timer not working? (Active = Until)

Tags: systemd, cron, docker, systemd-timer

I created a systemd-timer which should restart a docker container daily but it never does.
That uptime of the docker container is > 1 day, that shows me the container was not restarted

**/lib/systemd/system/rocketchat-restart.timer**

```
[Unit]
Description=timer to restart rocketchat docker container

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 04:45:00
Unit=rocketchat-restart.service
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**/lib/systemd/system/rocketchat-restart.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=service to restart rocketchat docker container

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker container restart rocketchat
```

**systemctl status rocketchat-restart.timer**

```
* rocketchat-restart.timer - timer to restart rocketchat docker container
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rocketchat-restart.timer; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (waiting) since Fri 2023-06-30 10:57:25 UTC; 1 week 3 days ago
      Until: Fri 2023-06-30 10:57:25 UTC; 1 week 3 days ago
    Trigger: Wed 2023-07-12 04:45:00 UTC; 20h left
   Triggers: * rocketchat-restart.service

Jun 30 10:57:25 docker systemd[1]: Started rocketchat-restart.timer - timer to restart rocketchat docker container.
```

**systemctl status rocketchat-restart.service**

```
* rocketchat-restart.service - service to restart rocketchat docker container
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rocketchat-restart.service; static)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2023-07-12 04:45:12 UTC; 6h ago
TriggeredBy: * rocketchat-restart.timer
    Process: 1794734 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker container restart rocketchat (code=exited, status=0/SUC>
   Main PID: 1794734 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 41ms

Jul 12 04:45:01 docker systemd[1]: Starting rocketchat-restart.service - service to restart rocketchat>
Jul 12 04:45:12 docker docker[1794734]: rocketchat
Jul 12 04:45:12 docker systemd[1]: rocketchat-restart.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jul 12 04:45:12 docker systemd[1]: Finished rocketchat-restart.service - service to restart rocketchat>
```

**systemctl list-timers | grep rocketchat-restart.timer**

```
NEXT                        LEFT          LAST                        PASSED       UNIT                         ACTIVAT
Wed 2023-07-12 04:45:00 UTC 20h left      Tue 2023-07-11 04:45:01 UTC 3h 49min ago rocketchat-restart.timer     rocketchat-restart.service
```

Is my service wrong?

Why is showing *Active:* and *Until:* the same date?

What does *Until:* mean?

What is wrong here?

Comment: What is the status of the service: `systemctl status rocketchat-restart.service`?  According to your posted `systemd list-timers`, the timer is triggering once per day so one would need to investigate what the service is doing.  The `Active` line is when the timer was activated within `systemd`.  I could not find information on `Until`, but it seems to only be on timer status and looks to always match the `Active` date.

Comment: i added the status of the service

Comment: but i think now (last night) it was working. i updated the server from debian 11 to 12 yesterday. i need to have an eye on this now.

Comment: Note: you should put self-made systemd unit files in `/etc/systemd/system`, not under `/lib/systemd/system`.

Comment: According to the posted status of `rocketchat-restart.service`, it was last executed on `Jul 12 04:45:01` and returned an exit code of `0/SUCCESS` so it looks like it is triggering properly.  What evidence do you have that it is not being triggered or the service is not being restarted?  How are you determining service uptime?

Comment: my proof that the docker container was not restarted was the "uptime" which i could see in portainer. before debian 12 it was untouched and i could see the time when i restarted manually the last time, like 21 days. but now with debian 12 it seems to work